# What are those wire terminals that mate with standard header pins?

Tags: connector, identification

I have purchased "dupont" connectors on Ebay that crimp onto a wire. They look like this:

http://www.hansenhobbies.com/products/connectors/pt1inconnectors/pt1in_ft/

[image: connector photo]

I'm tired of waiting weeks for these things to ship from China so I would like to purchase these from Mouser but I don't know what they're called or how to identify them on mouser's website. They are the standard rectangular wire terminal that is normally used to slip into a 2.54mm housing but I just use them without the housing because then slip snugly only standard header pins. Can someone tell me how to find these on Mouser?

**EDIT**

I just wanted to follow up on this because, as stated by The Photon, there are different varieties of contacts that are IMO quite significant.

[image: wire terminals]
<sub>(source: [ioplex.com](http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/wireterm.jpeg))</sub>

Regarding the above image:

On the left is a "dupont" connector from China via Ebay. Its contacts are slim and form a sleeve that holds header pin squarely. This limits wobble to one axis.

On the right is TE Connectivity 1-104480-2. Its contacts pinch the pin with two fingers. This allows wobble on both axis. And I can guess that the surface area of contact is less. It also has a spur that useless and potentially annoying when used without a housing.

So unfortunately I still have not successfully identified the correct part and as such I have reset this question as unanswered.

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0039000078/WM9154-ND/284604

Unfortunately there are hundreds of subtly different varieties of these "contacts", so its hard to know exactly which one is best for your situation. For example, the ones you link look like they're gold-plated. Do you need that feature?

Comment: This one's closer in price to yours: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0016020097/WM2513-ND/115066

Comment: Which crimp tool do you use for these connectors?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56477/what-is-this-connector-called?rq=1

Answer (score 12):

Those will be under the "Rectangular Connectors" heading of the [connectors section of their catalog](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/catalogusd/645/INTERSECTIONGUIDE.pdf). This is one instance where thumbing through the catalog is easier than the online version. Check out the [Molex SL Connectors on page 1623](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/645/usd/1623.pdf). More generically known as .100 inch headers.

Comment: Yup, that's it. Also the TE Connectivity 1-104480 series looks right. And it's a little shorter than the Molex version which I like because I want to use these without housings. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

http://tech.mattmillman.com/info/crimpconnectors/#minipv

Those 0.1" (2.54mm) crimp terminals with the triangular insulation crimp "wings" that are found basically everywhere are called Mini PV basics and are made by FCI Amphenol. There are countless knockoffs which is what you will usually find on ebay. They are NOT designed to be crimped with a generic double D crimp die, if you crimp a lot of them you should track down an HT-95 crimp tool as this will do the job correctly (and much more easily as it has a pin locating mechanism which frees you to just line up the wire and close the handle). You can find old Berg and Dupont branded ones on Ebay for under $100, new they cost over $1000. You would not believe how long it took me to find this information.

Answer (score 3):

The Harwin female crimp contacts ( M20-1160042 ) are a good match for the original question's picture and seem to me one of the better choices for the hobbyist as they can be used in both single and 2 row housings that can be found inexpensively all over the place (Jameco 100812 for instance).
  I can also vouch for the usefulness of the Japanese crimping pliers made by a company called "engineer" I've used my PA-21 on many projects and types of connector pins, and while manually crimping wire terminals is never going to be fun or fast, it is far less frustrating when the results are actually of consistently high quality.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately when it comes to connectors every manufacturer seems to have a different name for the same thing.

What I tend to do is go into the wire to board connectors section of the suppliers site, select pin count, row count and pin pitch (stnadard header pins are 0.1 inch or 2.54mm) then look through the pictures for ones that look right.

Once you find the right housing the datasheet should indicate the corresponding pins.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  It is not a trivial matter to just go pick one and hope it fits.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, however it popped on my screen and I get this question often when helping with arduino and other projects. If it is just for connecting to a header and only 1 position I will suggest using a housing such at Amp FCI part [65039-036LF](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/amphenol-fci/65039-036LF/609-2342-ND/1002657) This uses many contact one of them being [47212-000LF](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/amphenol-fci/47212-000LF/609-4792-ND/1492841) which is very similar to the one you have pictured.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

FYI Molex SL connectors will work just as well (better even) and have some nicer wire to wire connector options. They also have more reasonably priced official tooling, $140 for a service grade tool that has a locator and wire stop and they work better with generic crimpers as well.

Relevant parts, the terminals here are the 30 micron gold plated ones, there are cheaper ones with less gold or tin plating as well as a "high contact force" version (which is less forgiving of exact pin dimensions,so I don't use those) If you are using wire smaller than 22-24 AWG then you want the smaller gauge terminals for those wire sizes.

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0016020104/WM2564-ND/1118774

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0016020117/WM2567-ND/1118775

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0050579003/WM2801-ND/115005

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/50-57-9403/WM2901-ND/115034

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0701070002/WM2534-ND/210969

And the Molex service grade tool, these can be found used but make sure it has the terminal locator as I've seen units described as "working" that are missing this important part. Yeah the crimper "works" but it's worthless without the locator.

https://www.digikey.com/products/en?mpart=0640160201&v=900

The terminals have a spur that catches a hole in the housing which works opposite of how a dupont terminal works. This makes it easier to get the terminals out of the housing and they don't wiggle around as much either.

Comment: this guy crimps

Answer (score 0):

Search for m20-1060x00, where x is the numbers of required pins. Unfortunately for me, only from US or large quantity from china.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Harwin make a compatible crimp terminal http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-search/en?keywords=M20-1180042