# What is this connector called?

Tags: connector, identification

I need to repair some kit that uses several connectors like the one pictured below. The existing connections have become brittle and are breaking off.

The wires appear to be crimped into the connector somehow. Is there a special tool I need to re-attach them?

[image: connector]
[image: connector other side]

Comment: There was a recent question about the same type of connector: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/what-are-those-wire-terminals-that-mate-with-standard-header-pins

Comment: A picture of the other side, and/or the connector it plugs into would help.

Comment: These are used for standard Dupont-style wires for breadboarding.  The plastic header snaps into place over the crimped connectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update:*

As Passerby notes in a comment, the connector in your picture appears to be keyed. In which case it is not a generic 0.1" header connector. It may or may not have differing latching arrangements.

*Original Answer:*

> **What is the connector called**

They are called header connectors, designed for (usually) 0.1 inch pitch connectors. They mate with header pins.

The housings come as singles or as strips of several combined, you can make up cables from parts or buy pre-assembled sets like these:

- [2-pin 0.1" spacing pig-tails](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1003)
- [10-pin IDC Socket Rainbow Breakout Cable](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1199)
- [6-conductor 0.1" socket-socket cable](http://www.adafruit.com/products/206)
- [Female/Female Jumper Wires](http://www.adafruit.com/products/266)
- [Female/Male 'Extension' Jumper Wires](http://www.adafruit.com/products/826)

The last two items are useful in that you can tear off a group of as many connectors as needed for a specific application. You can cut the cable in half to make a lead that can be soldered at one end.

> **The wires appear to be crimped into the connector somehow.**

Usually the wire is crimped to a metal recaptacle and the assembly then is pushed into a housing that has a plastic latch to hold the assembly in place:

[image] one side has a latching tang
[image] use a knife to lift the retaining tang
[image] like so
[image] then the wire slides out of the housing

> **Is there a special tool I need to re-attach them?**

No, just push them back together, so long as the plastic tang is pushed into it's original position, it will lock the metal receptacle in place.

Comment: While they may be similar, or even interchangeable, the OP's picture shows a either a mated connector or a connector that's keyed. It's the split down the middle that makes it different. And without knowing what the other side looks like, we can't tell if there is a latch that holds the crimped part in place or not.

Comment: I'd recommend a solid color surface for photographing small parts. Yikes.

Comment: It's a cork mat I do soldering on :-) But point noted.

Comment: The plastic part is inserted over top of the internal wire-to-connector crimp.  You would never crimp through the plastic.  They snap in place when done properly.

Answer (score 1):

[Header connector](https://www.google.com/search?q=header%20connector); it connects to a pin header connector. The number of pins vary from one to another.

Edit:
In my country I can find them at an electronics store.
Here is what you need to buy, to give you an idea:
http://www.adelectrocom.ro/product_info.php?products_id=49312
http://www.adelectrocom.ro/product_info.php?products_id=82689

Edit:
Farnell links:

http://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/2226a-02/crimp-housing-1-row-2-way/dp/1593506
http://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/2226tg/crimp-terminal-24-28awg/dp/1593529

Comment: Instead of linking to products on the website of a Romanian supplier, you should link to global suppliers like Digikey or Farnell.