# Take out the jumper of breadboard wire

Tags: jumper

I have some breadboard wires as below photo, how can I take away the jumper out of the wire, I've tried to push the the slit on the jumper with no luck!

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you call "jumper" in the image?

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/56490/2191

Answer (score 2):

You have to *gently* lift the black plastic flap away from the uninsulated terminal below while pushing the wire further in; this will allow you to slip the wire and terminal out from the header connector. I recommend using a hobby knife that you can slide under the flap.

Comment: I like to do this with a small (precision/jeweler's) slotted screwdriver.

Comment: you'll need to cut away the metal part of the connector anyway since it's crimped for sure.

Comment: Unless you're going to turn around and insert it into a larger header connector instead.